# What can I use to back a door jamb strike plate with no framing behind?

Tags: screws, lock, old-house

So I'm trying to replace the original entrance handleset door lock from my almost 100 year old house and after removing the old lock and patching up the holes. I looked inside the door jamb and realized the inside has nothing for the screw to catch, it's all hollow inside.

The original lock had some kind of metal block installed inside so the screws for the original faceplate had something to adhere to.

So now I have 3 inch screws for my faceplate that has nothing to catch. Is there something I can buy to install it inside the door frame?? Or do I need to somehow stuff wood blocks inside the door frame to install my faceplate?

Answer (score 1):

I know of nothing short of installing something in the wall behind that frame - and oddly your door jamb does not have a stud there for the frame to mount to, as far as I know this has been common for a LONG LONG time.

From a security standpoint sounds like even the old system was there to keep honest weaklings from going rogue.

So you can remove that Jamb and install some framing stud in the back of it , use screws to attach it how you need to so you do not need to cut your wall, other wise you will need to cut that wall to fit and there are a couple options here - cut only at the top and bottom and remove the jamb or cut a piece all the way down and install the stud.

Comment: Thanks. That all sounds painful and more work than I had expected to do. Just to clarify for others, what I meant by 'faceplate' was 'strike plate'. In any case what if I put in a bunch of heavy duty wood filler to fill in the hollow space so my screws can catch that? I mean it may not be the the most solid solution for security but at least I will be able to install my new lock set and get it to work somewhat.

Comment: @miscellaneous I can tell you it will not work very well. if that is all you want to do - notch open your wall at the jamb about 8 inches long by 1 inch wide - insert a 1 x 4 x 12 and put screws to hold it in place. Or remove the door jamb and insert a stud behind it.

Comment: @Ken What type of wood should be used for the 1 x 4 x 12? I have a similar problem, but don't want to remove the entire door jamb. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/157741/door-jamb-rotted-where-latch-goes/157760#157760

Comment: @user8547 sorry for the delay  - I am overloaded right now. Given the fact that you will be squeezing the thing in and using only a 1 x 4 x 12 - use a good hard wood .. such as Oak - it is a bit pricier but it will do the trick , you could get away with pine - but it will not hold up - the new pine is softer than it used to be (especially the New Zealand pine- that is like balsa - pretty but soft). You might find your framing will cover up the 1 inch at the jamb just fine and escape the harder job.