# Door Jamb Rotted Where Latch Goes

Tags: doors, screws, lock, door-frame

I just installed a lock in my door and when attempting to install the latch I found that the wood was splintering and not stable, so I cut it out. My problem is similar to [this one](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/114751/what-can-i-use-to-back-a-door-jamb-strike-plate-with-no-framing-behind). What can be installed in the gap to make the latch have something strong to screw into? Best type of wood to use? Other ideas besides wood? Replacing the entire door frame is not an option at this point.
Reference image:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest replacing that jamb board. Measure the board and purchase a new board to replace it. Cut it completely out, top to bottom and install the new board. Cut your lockset holes and paint to match.

Comment: You suggest replacing the board from bottom to top on the one side with the cut-out? Or the entire jamb all the way around the door?Should I purchase something like this? https://www.homedepot.com/p/EverMark-11-16-in-x-4-9-16-in-x-81-11-16-in-Primed-Pine-Interior-Door-Jamb-Moulding-309-038C/202087160

Comment: search " door jamb Dutchman " and you will get all the info you need. https://duckduckgo.com/

Comment: Just the broken side,

Comment: @JeffCates What about the hollowed-out section between the trim and the stud? Should I cut some pine wood to fit that section and glue it in with wood glue?

Comment: That or replace the trim. I would replace any wood completely, glue/nail/screw will leave a weak spot especially where a lock is involved.